# Place sitemap on aws s3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a site with huge stack of links, each of them must placed on a sitemap. So my 2 mln. links was divided to several files, that united sitemap_index.xml. All files weighted about 300MB and devops said that this files must be on aws s3 bucket.

My question: can I correct place my sitemaps on aws s3 and this files are available for google/bing search robots.

I learn about it and my scenario.

1 Place all sitemap files on aws s3.
2 Write on example.com/robots.txt

Sitemap: http aws/sitemap_index.xml
in which are wrote all sitemap files

http  aws/parts/sitemap_$.xml

So on aws sitemap index file with my sitemaps (with direct links) placed on the same domain with index.xml

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems plausible and you considered the right things.

Google Bot / Bing Bot can read the sitemaps in your robots.txt
In their documentation that scenario is mentioned.

As you mentioned, your index Sitemap has to be in the same / parent location as your actual sitemaps. So everything is alright!

What you can't do with an outsourced stored sitemap is to add them to the respective Webmaster Tools as your domain is set.

- [Google Searchconsole Article - RU](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/large-sitemaps?hl=ru)
- [Google Searchconsole Article - EN](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/large-sitemaps?hl=en)

Depending on the number of sitemaps you could consider linking the sitemaps directly in your robots.txt instead of creating a index-sitemap.